# Is there any reason PeriodicWorkRequest not repeating on API level 23?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I'm trying to sync some data into the server at the end of the day ( like sync periodically 8 hours or something ). The PeriodicWorkRequest works fine with API level 21. But on API level 23 it's only called once. Not getting repeated at all.

Currently, I'm using the library 
android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.1. Tried changing it into android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.0-alpha04 still, it's not getting called repeatedly.

I'm calling it from the BaseActivity.

```
Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
            .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED).build();
    final PeriodicWorkRequest workRequest =
            new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(
            MyWorker.class,
            15,
            TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                    .setConstraints(constraints)
                    .build();

    WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(workRequest);


    WorkManager.getInstance().getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(workRequest.getId()).observe(this, new Observer<WorkInfo>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(WorkInfo workInfo) {


        }
    });
```

Comment: Latest WorkManager version is 2.1.0, it requires to move to androidx but it includes additional features and bugfixes not available in the 1.0.x branch.
If the error persist can you open a bug with a test application and information on the device you're testing this on [WorkManager's issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=409906&template=1094197)?

Comment: I have updated it to the latest library. Still, the issue persists. I read somewhere it might be due to the 'doze' thing in Oreo and all. Is there any way to fix this issue?

Comment: I'm facing a likewise issue only on API 23 though. Tried it on API 29, where my worker is called every 15 mins exactly as i set it too. On API 23, it gets called randomly for me!

Comment: Hi all, I am using dependency "android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.1",Workmanager not working in API 23. Please help me on this.